# Delayed Job method not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

```
Rails 5.1
```

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
```

In app/jobs/application_job.rb, I have:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
end
```

In app/jobs/create_csv.rb, I have:

```
class CreateCsvJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(followed_id)
    ........
  end
end
```

In app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb, I have:

```
def create_csv
  CreateCsvJob.perform_later(params[:followed_id])
  redirect_to root_path, notice: t('fw_exports.spreadsheet_export.csv_generation_started')
end
```

But, when I run the action to create a CSV, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant FwExportsController::CreateCsvJob
```

However, I have another delayed action, that's working fine

In app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb, I have:

```
def process_parsed_spreadsheet
  ParseAndProcessSpreadsheetJob.perform_later(params[:temp_file_path], params[:followed_id])
  redirect_to root_path, notice: t('fw_exports.file_successfully_imported')
end
```

In app/jobs/parse_and_process_spreadsheet_job.rb, I have:

```
class ParseAndProcessSpreadsheetJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(temp_file_path, followed_id)
    .........
  end
end
```

The latter one, runs fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the filename of create_csv.rb to create_csv_job.rb. Does that help?